# Change password in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

EDIT: **All I need is render /devise/registrations/edit in /settings/password**

To do that put this your view e.g. /settings/password

```
<%= render :template => 'devise/registrations/edit' %>
```

and This in SettingsHelper

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource = current_user || User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end

def devise_error_messages!
  return "" if resource.errors.empty?

  messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
  sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                    :count => resource.errors.count,
                    :resource => resource_name)

  html = <<-HTML
          <div id='error'>
            <h2>{sentence}<h2>
            <p>#{messages}</p>

        </div>
  HTML

  html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 #routes.rb
 get 'settings/password' => 'users#password'
```

And then in your controller, create the action password:

```
#users_controller.rb
def password
  redirect_to :edit
end
```

If you are using Rails 3, you can simply do this:

```
 #routes.rb
 get 'settings/password' => redirect('users/edit')
```

Maybe this is what you are after?

```
 #routes.rb
 devise_for :users do
   get 'settings/password' => 'devise/registrations#edit'
 end
```

Comment: hmm, in this case I would go with 'user#edit' but I don't want a redirect, I just want /settings/password to stay in url. Kinda hidden alias if I can call it.

Comment: If you want /settings/password to stay in the url and you want to call the action edit on users, what's the problem with doing `get 'settings/password' => 'users#edit'`?

Comment: well its not working doing that. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: Aah, I see, so you are using devise (guess I didn't notice the tag). Maybe you should edit your question and clarify a bit more what you want to do. You want to give a user the option of editing his account without having to input his password and the option of changing his password, is that it?

Comment: All I need is render /devise/registrations/edit in /settings/password so Users can change their password from there instead of /users/edit. when I render like :  <%= render :template => 'devise/registrations/edit', 
                          :locals => { 
                            :resource => "user", 
                            :resource_name => "user" } %> I get undefined local variable or method `resource'

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand the part about rendering that template, but if you are simply trying to allow a different url to access that action, then try the following (see my edited answer).

Comment: well, I got confused too, all I need is to be able to change password from settings controller instead of devise/registrations/edit. Thats why I was trying to render view from devise/registrations/edit to /settings/password but I am getting undefined local variable or method `resource', I have tried all kind of resource. maybe I need a break, and a kitkat :(

Comment: Thanks for trying this with me. There is no other solution.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you do what you wanted to do. Perhaps you shouldn't have accepted my answer and waited for someone else to help you.

Comment: since the answer has solution, your good and in devise wiki has been change, but it doesnt work.